# Angular - Send a request with multiple models to API

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular-httpclient

I'm new in Angular, and I'm currently into a big project where many people work, so the project is based on Angular for the front end and C# for the back end.

So, the project has some services that call the backend service:

Front:

```
public editProfileClient(profileClient) {
  return this.http
    .post(this.url + '/editProfileClient', profileClient)
    .pipe(map((result: ProfileClientModel) => result));
}
```

Back:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfileClient(ProfileClient profileClient)
{
    //irrelevant code here
    return Ok(model);
}
```

This is working well, but now I want to send a new model called `Salary` to that request, so I changed the back as:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfileClient(ProfileClient profileClient, Salary salary)
```

but I have no idea how I can send it on the front, so I receive it, but I cannot call it:

```
public editProfileClient(profileClient, salary) {
  return this.http
    .post(this.url + '/editProfileClient', profileClient, salary)
    .pipe(map((result: ProfileClientModel) => result));
}
```

If I try to do that, the method returns an error:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<ProfileClientModel,
> ProfileClientModel>' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'OperatorFunction<ArrayBuffer, ProfileClientModel>'.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the API part, combine both parameters into a single object as below:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfileClient(EditProfileClientInputModel input)
```

```cs
public class EditProfileClientInputModel
{
    public ProfileClient ProfileClient { get; set; }
    public Salary Salary { get; set; }
}
```

2. For the front-end part:

   2.1. Combine both `profileClient` and `salary` parameters into a single object and pass it.

   2.2. As your API returns the response of `ProfileClientModel` type, you should also specify the generic type: `post<T>()`

```js
public editProfileClient(profileClient, salary) {
  let input = {
    profileClient: profileClient,
    salary: salary
  };

  return this.http
    .post<ProfileClientModel>(this.url + '/editProfileClient', input);
}
```

**Update**

```
.pipe(map((result: ProfileClientModel) => result))
```

As per Eliseo's feedback, the `pipe()` should be removed as `map()` is used to transform the data, while you try to transform the value into the same value, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Please, not use `map` to do "nothing". map is for transform a response. If you retrun the same variable, remove the pipe(map). It's uneccessay.

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, you are right, didn't realize that the `.map()` is unnecessary. Will update to the answer. Thanks for the feedback.